# Populate multiple data tables using one data entry form

Tags: excel

I haven't used macros for a while and I am getting a bit bogged down on something simple.

I am trying to populate multiple data tables using one data entry form. For example, I have 4 stores. I need to enter daily inventory, sales, deposits, etc. Each store has its own table in a separate worksheet. I want the data entry clerk to be able to select the store # and date and then enter inventory, sales and a daily deposit and then submit. Once the data is submitted I want it to populate the appropriate table on the appropriate worksheet organized by the date. After the data is submitted I want the data entry box to reset to blanks so that the next entry can be made.

Any steer in the right direction would be most helpful

Thanks!

Comment: Next time, please choose a more descriptive question title than "Excel Macro Question". I've changed it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to VBAProject, right click -> Insert -> User Form. Create a user form - something like:
[image]

You can pre-populate Store and Inventory combo boxes to make life easier. To start a from you can use a button places on a sheet and wire its Click event. You will end up with something like:

```
Public frmEntry As UserForm1

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    If frmEntry Is Nothing Then

        Set frmEntry = New UserForm1

        Call PopulateStores()
        Call PopulateInventory()

    End If

    frmEntry .Show Modal

End Sub
```

On the submit side - you need to handle Click event on the Submit button.

Answer (score 1):

This link will help you create your data entry from: http://www.contextures.com/xluserform01.html

When the user is finished entering data on the form (after he clicks the "Finish" button for example), simply write the data in the controls (like a textbox) onto the appropriate worksheet and cells. For example, add this code to your userfrom:

```
Private Sub btnFinish_Click()
    Worksheets("Store1").Cells(2,3).Value2 = Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```